# Synchronized access to Operation Contract WCF

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I have a WCF service, which has an operation contract called `GetEmail`. `GetEmail` pull an email from a database table. The requirement is to sent unique email content to individual user (consumers of this service). This means no two user will have handle over a single email content. But this is been violated because of the WCF service design. Specifically, the WCF `Concurrency` and `InstanceContent` mode. Sorry I can't change service design at this stage.

**Question**: Is it possible to build a synchronized access on Email content without making changes to service design or database table (locking). Ideally, calls has to queue up on my `GetEmail` operation contract. I read about `IExtensibleObject<T>` but can't associate it with my case.

```
[ErrorBehavior(typeof(ErrorHandler))]
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class EmailRepository : IEmailRepository
    {
        public string GetEmail(Guid IdUser)
        {
            //Logic to retrive one email based on data of receive
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the database side of things looks like? Do you record on the database who the address was given to? If not, how do you keep track?

Comment: @JeffBridgman, We have a column called lockedby, which will have the IdUser(who got the message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it:

```
[ErrorBehavior(typeof(ErrorHandler))]
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class EmailRepository : IEmailRepository
{
    private static object _lockOb = new object();
    public string GetEmail(Guid IdUser)
    {
        lock(_lockOb)
        {
            //Logic to retrive one email based on data of receive
        }
    }
}
```

The lock will serialize access to the email, so only one call and be handled at a time. It assumes that when you retrieve the e-mail, you move your reference to the next email all inside the lock. It also assumes that this is the only way to retrieve those e-mails. Any other method that can retrieve them will need to share the same lock object.

Comment: Thanks for the post. However, I am not sure your logic since my service context mode is not Singleton and is PerCall. This means, you will get different lock objects for each operation call. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Nair The lock object is static, so it will serialize access, even across multiple instances of the service.

Comment: static fields are app domain specific (at least in terms of c# and clr). Is this hold true in WCF infrastructure ?

Comment: Your WCF service will run in a single app domain, so yes. The exception would be if you have multiple servers (or multiple sites on a server) with your WCF service. That is if, for example, you have 3 servers with your WCF service, its access would be serialized on each of those 3 servers, but not between them. But as long as you only have one site hosting your WCF service, then a static object will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When you say multiple servers, are you talking about physical load balancer ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to be much clearer. It's a static variable in a WCF service. There will be 1 instance per app domain running your WCF service... So if you have your service running in multiple app domains (either on the same machine or different machines), this will not work.

Comment: Your briefing was very clear apart from one point. In my case, my service is deployed in one server, WCF instance context mode is PerCall and Concurrency is Multiple. I presume, as and when user ( from different machine) access the service parallely, WCF run-time will dispatch new instances per thread, where each instance got it's own AppDomain. Is this true ?

Comment: Per call is merely a new service/object instance per call, not a new app domain. All object instances will share the same static variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think that putting the responsibility of synchronized access on the database would be the best approach here. Most databases have the concept of transactions which should allow you to accomplish your goal.

To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction):

> [Transactions] provide isolation between programs accessing a database concurrently.

Comment: Correct and I agree with you. As I said, I have no control over database. So nothing on that front.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't have control of the code that calls the database? Because I don't think you'd need to do anything to the database _itself_, you just have to write code to create a transaction and run your SQL statements in the context of the transaction to get concurrency.

Comment: We have a stored procedure, written in c# (SQL CLR) and deployed in SQL Server. This means, I have access to the code, which is a stored procedure. But don't have access to database in order to deploy it. Did I answer your question

Comment: It looks like the transaction for a stored procedure can be managed in the stored procedure itself, or the code that calls it. Unfortunately, I've never worked with sql server or stored procedures before. However, this [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/12414411#12414411) suggests it should be possible.